# Unable to observe livedata set in viewmodel from activity

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

I am a newbie Android developer, and I am trying to observe a boolean set in the ViewModel from its parent's activity. I can observe its initial state as soon as the app launches, but any change applied later on doesn't seem to trigger the observer (i.e. when I switch the fragments).

Here is the code for my ViewModel:

```
class MyMusicViewModel  : ViewModel() {


    private var _MyMusicViewOn = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val MyMusicViewOn: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _MyMusicViewOn



    init {
        Timber.i("MyMusicViewModel Init Called!")
        setMyMusicView(true)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Timber.i("MyMusicViewModel Cleared!")
        setMyMusicView(false)
    }


    fun setMyMusicView(setter: Boolean) {
        Timber.i("MyMusicViewModel setter called! %s", setter)
        _MyMusicViewOn.value = setter
    }


}
```

And here is its parent's activity:

```
class FullscreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val viewModel: MyMusicViewModel by viewModels()

  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       
        viewModel.MyMusicViewOn.observe(this, Observer { MyMusicViewOn ->
            Timber.i("Observer called for MyMusicViewOn %s", MyMusicViewOn)
        })

    }

}
```

And in case you wanna see the ViewModel's related fragment, here it is:

```
class MyMusicFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyMusicViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentMyMusicBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_my_music,
            container,
            false
        )
        
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyMusicViewModel::class.java)

        return binding.root
    }
    

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        Timber.i("MyMusicViewFragment resumed!")
        viewModel.setMyMusicView(true)

    }




}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to observe the onResume(), onCleared() and init{} functions whenever they are called by changing the status of the MyMusicViewOn MutableLiveData Boolean. What I don't understand is why that boolean doesn't trigger the observer set in the parent activity whenever it changes.

Thankyou in advance for any thoughts!

All the best,

Fab.

Comment: You have a `lateinit var viewModel: MyMusicViewModel` in your `MyMusicFragment`, but you haven't included any code that sets that `viewModel` object. Can you include that code?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I forgot to include that code. I have edited my post above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that however you are populating that `viewModel` property in your Fragment, you are not using the Activity's ViewModel instance. The easiest way to get the same instance that the Activity is using would be to use the `activityViewModels` delegate:

```
private val viewModel: MyMusicViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok, I guess that line must be put inside the Fragment in place of the "private lateinit var viewModel: MyMusicViewModel". Am I correct? I did that, but I then had an error with "viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyMusicViewModel::class.java)" later in, so I removed that line and no errors were given, and I could run the app, and now I see the variable MyMusicViewOn observed correctly every time is set to "true" but... never when set to "false". Any ideas?

Comment: You are setting it to `false` inside `onCleared()`, which means activity is in inactive state, as `Livedata` is lifecycleaware it won't publish those changes.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. And as @rajan.kali said, `onCleared` is called after the activity with the observer is already detached, so there is no more observer to log the change to false.

Comment: Thank you guys! All clear now, that makes sense. I have a plan to deal with all this then. Thank you again very much!